How to prove that the sequence $a_n=\frac{(\ln(\ln(n)))^q}{n\ln(n)}$ is decreasing?
In a lecture today, we looked at the sequence $$a_n=\frac{(\ln(\ln(n)))^q}{n\ln(n)},$$ where $q$ is a rational number. We had to show that the sequence is decreasing from a certain point. It seems completely obvious, but I wasn't able to prove it completely rigorously. We also cannot use any rules for limits with logs, or derivatives.

Was that indeed the exercise? To show that the sequence is decreasing? Or you had to show it for something else?

Compute $$\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n} = \frac{\ln(\ln(n + 1))^q}{\ln(\ln(n))^q} \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln(n + 1)} \frac{n}{n + 1}\cdot$$
Over $[\exp(q); +\infty[$, the function $x \mapsto \frac{\ln(x)^q}{x}$ is decreasing, which gives for $n \geqslant \exp(\exp(q))$: $$\frac{\ln(\ln(n + 1))^q}{\ln(\ln(n))^q} \leqslant \frac{\ln(n + 1)}{\ln(n)},$$
Hence $\frac{a_{n + 1}}{a_n}\leqslant \frac{n}{n + 1} < 1$, therefore $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is strictly decreasing from a certain point.
